# Memory needed for opening heap dumps .hprof

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, visualvm, hprof

If I use any Java application like VisualVM to open a heap dump (hprof file), would I need more heap memory for VisualVM than hprof file size?

In my case, hprof is 4Gb file and VisualVM has 2 GB Heap size and it's fails to properly load HPROF file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need more heap memory for VisualVM than hprof file size. VisualVM does not load heap dump into JDK heap. It uses memory-mapped files instead. This way it can use a lot of memory even if the default Xmx for VisualVM is 256M.

Comment: Any references ?

Comment: References to what?